# Short question: Any good way to view a forms querystring?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, browser

I have a form which uses the "GET" method.

This might be a stupid question...

I would need to view the full querystring somehow, of the form when submitting it?

I have Firebug if that would help somehow...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, you can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

In Firebug, it's a matter of going to the Network tab and selecting the request. The query string will be in the request line after the first `?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`window.location.search`](http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-Location-Search-with-Examples.aspx) from javascript or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` from php.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use the FireFox extension [`Tamper Data`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/) for this.  It's easy to use, and lets you change or view any piece of information about the request prior to its being submitted...  I highly recommend it if you want to request parameters on the fly...

Answer (score 0):

For the client side, here is a pretty decent article on parsing in Javascript:

http://support.internetconnection.net/CODE_LIBRARY/javascript_Parsing_Query_String.shtml